# Problem with ArrayList not showing correct size

Tags: java, arraylist

So I've got this code which will add the numbers 1-9 into separate ArrayLists if the ArrayList doesn't exist. However, even though I print the ArrayLists(and it gets me all the correct numbers), when I print the .size of the ArrayList, it gives me 1 instead of 9. I hope you understand my problem. Here's the code:

```
ArrayList[][] tillatnaSiffror = new ArrayList[9][9];

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        for(int ruta=0;ruta<9;ruta++){

            if(tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta] == null){
                for(int add=1;add<=9;add++){
                    tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta].add(add);
                    System.out.println(tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta]);
                }
                System.out.println(tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta].size());
            }
        }
    }
```

That gives me this(although nine times of course): `[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9]1`

Now I'm wondering, WHY do I get 1 instead of 9 when I print .size?

Comment: What does **tillatnaSiffror** mean and what language is it, I wonder?

Comment: `tillatnaSiffror` means "allowed numbers". I assume Filip is writing a soduko-solver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you **reset the list in each iteration** by doing

```
tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

i.e., you create a new list, throwing away the previous one for each digit you add!

Try moving out the creation of the list:

```
 ,-->   tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 |      for(int add=1;add<=9;add++){
 '-----<
            tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta].add(add);
            System.out.println(tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta]);
         }
```

---

[**Ideone.com demo**](http://ideone.com/pEUtc)

---

As a side note, I would suggest to avoid arrays here, and use Java collections all the way. Consider for instance to use a structure like `List<List<Set<Integer>>>`.

Comment: Aaah! Of course.. I'll blame it on lack of sleep ;) Thanks a lot for pointing that out, and I'll take your idea with Collections for consideration!